# How To Load JSON Into an ag-grid Table (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I'm new to using ag-grid and am implementing it into my React project. With this, I've made the following table:

```
class Table extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)

     this.state = {
        columnDefs: [
            { headerName: "Column 1", field: "col1"},
        ],
        rowData: [
            { 'col1': 'Hello'},
            { 'col1': 'World'},
        ],
      }
   }

   render() {
      return (
        <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: 605 }}>
            <AgGridReact
                columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                rowData={this.state.rowData}>
            </AgGridReact>
        </div>
      );
    }
};
```

Now, I have the ability to get JSON using `.fetch` and would like to load the JSON values into my table. For example, say my JSON comes in like so:

```
{'col1': 'Jeff',
 'col1' : 'Sophie',
 'col1' : 'Kelly'}
```

How would I load these values into my table above? I've tried adding the following `componentDidMount` method to the Table, but the table then greys itself out and says 'loading...' and never finishes loading:

```
 componentDidMount(){
      myData= getData()  //method calls fetch and returns my JSON items
      this.setState({
            rowData: myData
       });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've provided, there's nothing that I can see that would cause this issue. It could be to do with your `getData` function.

See this sample that sets `rowData` on `componentDidMount` by calling `fetch`:
https://plnkr.co/edit/K2gC2Qc6tKc3huTT

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const updateData = (data) => {
      this.setState({ rowData: data });
    };

    fetch('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json')
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data) => updateData(data));
  }
```